# file upload using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have coded a simple html form for file uploading using bootstrap framework and jquery. In the server side i try to print the name of file when the file has been uploaded successful.

The problem is that the filename doesn't be printed. What i do in the server is 
`echo $_FILE['file']['name']` . The full script is here http://pastebin.com/eEpAy1Tg

i don't know a lot about jquery and bootstrap. Maybe i dont upload the file in success due to jquery and bootstrap. If anyone has expirience and could help me i appreciate it.

Comment: if you bring the code here we can help you. on stackoverflow code are clearly highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

try;

change

```
<form action="index1.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="index1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I have just tried. Well if i do print_r($_FILES['file1']['type']); it prints me "text/plain". If i do  echo $_FILE['file1']['type']; it prints nothing.

also the print_r($_FILES); gives Array ( [file1] => Array ( [name] => file.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpHJj5h4 [error] => 0 [size] => 12 ) )

the condition  ($_FILE['file1']['type']== 'text/plain') isn't true... why?